# Update textview when value in a different class is updated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I am trying to update a textview to a value (a timer) within my current xml im viewing, the java for the timer is part of a glrenderer class, everything works fine, except I can't update my textview,  I have already extended Activity to the class like this:

`class MyGLRenderer extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {`

So that I am able to use this inside the timer loop:

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetextview);
view.setText(String.valueOf(globals.gametime));
```

It crashes when it tries to create the viewtime object.

There is one way I can get it to partially, the Timer value is a global one so I can show it by creating a button in the main.java like so:

```
public void buttonExample (View v) 
{
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetextview);
    view.setText(String.valueOf(globals.gametime));
}
```

But with this it wont update with the actual timer, I'm unsure why its crashing when I'm using the top 2 blocks of code, it compiles fine.

Comment: post the log with the error

Answer (score 0):

I doubt , you are updating the Textview in timer thread .

You can try this in your timer thread -

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
            view.setText(String.valueOf(globals.gametime));
           }
        });
```

Comment: cool...if this is answer..then you can tick/vote up on right answer...so It would helpful in future for other folks !!

Answer (score 0):

Using the code Gaurav provided to access the uithread in my timer worked perfectly, here is what I used

```
public Timer timer = new Timer();


timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
               TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetextview);
               view.setText(String.valueOf(globals.GameTime));
                }
          });
      }
}, 250, 250);
```